# Tizen studio add real device

Tags: watch, tizen, galaxy

after problem with signature while try to run my APP on real device I reset the watch and create Samsung Certificate.

Now i have a problem that i can`t add this watch to Tizen Studio Device Manager even if i can switch connect in Remote Device manager.
At this moment I tried turn debug on and restart watch.

Windows 10
Tizen Studio 3.6

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:
This worked for me https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/general-support/device-manager-cannot-connect-galaxy-watch-46mm.-bluetooth-off-debugging-on-developer-options-same-wifi-network.
Switch state of debuging, then restart watch, then scan for devices in device manager.
After 7 times i got RSA key to confirm on my watch.